# What LinkedIn API permission am I missing to get organization target name?

Tags: linkedin-api

Using LinkedIn API v2.0 I'm currently trying to get a list of organisation ids and names for authenticated user that they are administrator of. I'm able to get all organisation ids using:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&start=0&count=100&fields=organizationalTarget&oauth2_access_token={{OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN}}`

but when I add `"organizationTarget~"` as apart of fields parameter I get an error saying

> "not enough permissions to access field organizationalTarget~ for
>   GET-roleAssignee /organizationalEntityAcls"

Should I be using a different endpoint to get this data or what permission am I missing? I currently am using **r_basicprofile**, **rw_company_admin**, and **rw_organization** scopes while authenticating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this API call:

```
 curl -i -X GET \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer <ACCESS-TOKEN>" \
 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&projection=(elements*(organizationalTarget~(localizedName)))'
```

Hope this help

Comment: Excuse me, how would this be for the php version?

Comment: Hi @NeftaliAcosta you are talking about some SDK/Library? Could you share them (Github repo/code...) please?

Comment: @Matteo Can you see my link please? Thanks for your time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425070/how-get-companies-linkedin-api-v2-in-php

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/permissions-resources-mapping

"rw_organization_admin" is the missing scope.