# LinkedIn v2 organization API endpoint failing

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm currently requesting scopes `w_company_admin`, `r_basicprofile`, and `rw_organization`.

I already posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890861/what-linkedin-api-permission-am-i-missing-to-get-organization-target-name), but I got no support so I'm trying a different approach.

I found another endpoint that should get me the organization name. I used this endpoint to get ID of organizations:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&start=0&count=100&fields=organizationalTarget&oauth2_access_token='.$oauth_token;
```

Then when I extract the ID from urn leaving me with just ID number I use that in this request

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/'.$company_id.'?projection=(elements*(entity~(vanityName)))&oauth2_access_token='.$oauth_token;
```

The problem is that this request is returning **200** status with the output being `"{}"`.

I don't understand why no data would be returned? It seems like the API request is failing considering the first request worked successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate the problem, you should use a different projection. 
Use this:

```
projection=(vanityName)
```

Instead of this:

```
projection=(elements*(entity~(vanityName)))
```

Probably the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api#retrieve-organizations) seems misleading about the usage of the decorator in this case.

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you so much that worked perfectly! Is there a way to grab the name from first API request like my original question I linked to? Or am I missing the rw_organization_admin scope like Steven Kuck mentioned in his answer above

Comment: Hi @DerekJosephOlson I take a look at the other question but seems a problem related to the permission of the token: I don't experience any errors on your call

Comment: @DerekJosephOlson I try to response with an api call. Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Reposted an answer to your original question:
I found the answer on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/permissions-resources-mapping

"rw_organization_admin" is the missing scope.